# Issue with getting files of certain text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop

I want to check if each sub string in a list `req_text` is contained in any of the files in list `all_files`  or not. Program should return True only when each sub string in a list `req_text` is contained in at least one file in list `all_files`. if even one sub string is not present in any of the files in list `all_files`  then it should return False.

```
all_files = ['amc_20200304.txt', 'hello.py', 'pmc_20190807.txt', 'pmc_20200304.txt', 'pmc_20304.txt']
req_text = ['pmc_20304', 'amc_20200304']

def file_check():    
    all_files = os.listdir(dir)
    print(all_files)
    for f in all_files:     
        for r in req_txt:    
            if r in f:
                print("file exists: " + f)               
                return True
            else:
                print("file not exists: " + f)
                return False

def printt():
    result = file_check()
    print(result)
printt()
```

Current result: It is saying that amc_20200304.txt doesn't exist but it exist because file is there in the list `all_files`

```
file not exists: amc_20200304.txt
False
```

Expected: It should return true because both the sub strings in list `req_text` are contained in the files in list `all_files` . if any of the sub string is missing in any of the files in list all_files  then it should return False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few mistakes.

1. all_files is overwritten as part of `all_files = os.listdir(dir)`
2. The return statement inside the else part will return when the 1st comparison is made between `amc_20200304.txt` and `pmc_20304`

Below is what you want.

```py
all_files = ['amc_20200304.txt', 'hello.py', 'pmc_20190807.txt', 'pmc_20200304.txt', 'pmc_20304.txt']
req_text = ['pmc_20304', 'amc_20200304']

def file_check():    
    print(all_files)
    for r in req_text:
        found = False
        for f in all_files:    
            if r in f:
                print("file exists: " + f)               
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            print("pattern not exists: " + r)
            return False
    return True

def printt():
    result = file_check()
    print(result)
printt()
```

Output

```
file exists: pmc_20304.txt
file exists: amc_20200304.txt
True
```